# Spyder Python IDE thinks remote kernel has died when it hasn't; any ways to prevent that?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ipython, spyder

I'm running Spyder on Windows connecting remotely to and Amazon EC2 ipython kernel. Whenever I run some operations that take more than a few seconds to run, I get the repeated message

> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to
>   continue using this console.

But my kernel is all fine and dandy. Sometimes I have to press Enter repeatedly to make it snap out of it, other times I have to restart the Spyder console and connect to my still-alive kernel.

Any tips? Is there a way to disable the kernel-death check, or increasing the timeout?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I often have the same problem, the easiest and fastest fix I have for you at the moment, is running the code in a new dedicated python console every time. this can easily be done by:

1) click the run settings icon (the wrench with green play/run buttton in the top of your screen)

2) Select the 2nd option (execute in a new dedicated python console)

3) press ok

This will automatically run the code in a new console next time you press the run file button (f5), and should prevent the error message.